# ASP NET MVC 5 i18n using Nadeem's code, but I want to add returnUrl

Tags: internationalization, asp.net-mvc-5, resx, returnurl

I am going to include the code how I have it. I felt like what I had should work because I got no squiggly lines. lol But I end up with a Redirect Loop.

First off I got the basic implementation from [Nadeem Afana's blog](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx). I don't think the CultureHelper.cs or the BaseController.cs may be needed to implement a returnUrl functionality, but since they are part of the code I am including them here so that you don't have to dig through his website to look for it. I have tried to eliminate scrolling for you as well.

HERE IS MY CODE:

**Helpers/CultureHelper.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;

namespace xxxUSA.Helpers
{
    public static class CultureHelper
    {
        // Valid cultures REMOVED SOME CODES FOR BREVITY
        private static readonly List<string> _validCultures = new List<string> 
        { "en-AU", "en-BZ", "en-CA", "en-029", "en-IN", "en-IE", "en-JM", 
          "en-MY", "en-NZ", "en-PH", "en-SG", "en-ZA", "en-TT", "en-GB", 
          "en-US", "en-ZW", "es-CR", "es-DO", "es-EC", "es-SV", "es-GT", 
          "es-HN", "es-MX", "es-NI", "es-PA", "es-PY", "es-PE", "es-PR", 
          "es-ES", "es-US", "es-UY", "es-VE" };

        private static readonly List<string> _cultures = new List<string> {
            "en-US",  // first culture is the DEFAULT
            "es", // Spanish NEUTRAL culture
            "ar"  // Arabic NEUTRAL culture
        };

        public static bool IsRightToLeft()
        {
            return 
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread
            .CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft;
        }

        public static string GetImplementedCulture(string name)
        {
            // make sure it's not null
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                return GetDefaultCulture(); // return Default culture

            if (_validCultures.Where(c => c.Equals(name, 
                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Count() == 0)
                return GetDefaultCulture(); // return Default if invalid

            if (_cultures.Where(c => c.Equals(name, 
                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Count() > 0)
                return name; // accept it

            var n = GetNeutralCulture(name);
            foreach (var c in _cultures)
                if (c.StartsWith(n))
                    return c;

            return GetDefaultCulture(); // return Default if no match
        }

        public static string GetDefaultCulture()
        {
            return _cultures[0]; // return Default culture
        }

        public static string GetCurrentCulture()
        {
            return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
        }

        public static string GetCurrentNeutralCulture()
        {
            return GetNeutralCulture(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
        }

        public static string GetNeutralCulture(string name)
        {
            if (name.Length < 2)
                return name;

            return name.Substring(0, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controllers/BaseController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using xxxUSA.Helpers;

namespace xxxUSA.Controllers
{
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {

        protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(
                                        AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        {
            string cultureName = null;

            // Attempt to read the culture cookie from Request
            HttpCookie cultureCookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
            if (cultureCookie != null)
                cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
            else
                cultureName = Request.UserLanguages != null && 
                Request.UserLanguages.Length > 0 ? Request.UserLanguages[0] 
                : null; // obtain it from HTTP header AcceptLanguages

            // Validate culture name
            cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName);

            // Modify current thread's cultures            
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

            return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
        }
    }
}
```

OK, now we get into where I have modified some things. I will comment on anything I added

**Controllers/HomeController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using xxxUSA.Helpers;
using xxxUSA.Models;

namespace xxxUSA.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {

    ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }

                                                  //I ADDED THIS LAST PARAMETER
    public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture, string returnUrl)
    {
        // Validate input
        culture = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(culture);

        // Save culture in a cookie
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
        if (cookie != null)
            cookie.Value = culture;   // update cookie value
        else
        {

            cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
            cookie.Value = culture;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        }
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);


        //THIS WORKS
        return Redirect(returnUrl);

        //THIS DOES NOT
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }



    }
```

Now for the code on the Home Page

**Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread
    .CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLowerInvariant();
    ViewBag.Title = culture;
}

                                         //I ADDED THIS LAST PARAMETER
@helper selected(string c, string culture, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (c == culture)
    {
        @:checked="checked"
    }
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SetCulture", "Home"))
{
@Resources.ChooseYourLanguage &nbsp;&nbsp;

<input name="culture" id="en-us" value="en-us" 
                                        //I ADDED THIS LAST PARAMETER "About"
type="radio" @selected("en-us", culture, "About") /> English 

<input type="Hidden" name="returnUrl" value="About" />

<input name="culture" id="es" value="es"  
                                    //I ADDED THIS LAST PARAMETER "About"
type="radio" @selected("es", culture, "About") /> Español
}

//LOTS OF STUFF LOADS HERE LIKE RESOURCE REFERENCES, GRAPHICS, CONTENT, 
//NOT IMPORTANT FOR THE IMPLEMENTATION REMOVED FOR BREVITY

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $("input[type = 'radio']").click(function () {
            $(this).parents("form").submit(); // post form
        });

    })(jQuery);
</script> 
}
```

So the reason I added the "About" was so if I got it to work, It would redirect to the "About" Action instead of back to the same homepage. It doesn't work though.

Can I not overload the checkboxes @Selected Method the way I have?

Also, NOT IMPORTANT NOW, but what if I wanted to add this to other views from other controllers, Could I include another parameter to designate the controller and action it needs to return to so that I don't have to repeat the code in each controller?

I have contacted Nadeem on twitter and he said he would check it out and try and help. I really appreciate his work and seems like a very kind fellow.. Thanks in advance for simply helping in any capacity!

OK so I have a products/Ingredients page where I have stuff coming from the database, here how I hacked that to show the right field from the database. This is a total HACK BEWARE.

**Views/Products.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<xxxUSA.Models.Ingredient>

@{
    var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread
                  .CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLowerInvariant();
    ViewBag.Title = culture;
}
@helper selected(string c, string culture)
{
    if (c == culture)
    {@:checked="checked"}
}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
            @using(Html.BeginForm("SetCulture", "Ingredient"))
{        

  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <label>@Resources.ChooseYourLanguage</label>
      <input type="Hidden" name="returnUrl" value="/Prodcuts/" />
      <input name="culture" id="en-us" value="en-us" type="radio" 
                           @selected("en-us", culture) /> English
     <input name="culture" id="es" value="es" type="radio" 
                           @selected("es", culture) /> Español
    </div>
  </div>
}
@{ViewBag.Culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread
.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLowerInvariant();}

//Here is where the conditional logic hack I use to show one field 
//or another from the database based on culture

@if (ViewBag.Culture == "en-us") {
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IngredientNameEn)
} else { 
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IngredientNameEs) }
```

Basically using that conditional logic anywhere I have data that has a spanish or english version. it's hacky as hell though.

Comment: First, have you tried 
   return Redirect(returnUrl); 

instead of return RedirectToAction(returnUrl); ?

Comment: also,  selected helper receives a returnUrl parameter but it's not doing anything with it.

Comment: Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: url Line 102:  return Redirect(returnUrl);

Comment: SO I need to make a change in the CultureHelper.cs page catch the returnUrl so that when the SetCulture Action calls for it, it's there?

Comment: The returnUrl in the code above seems to be null because you are not setting a value in the <form>. Add a hidden input called returnUrl with a value "/About"

Comment: What about the @selected("es", culture, "About") Do I remove the "About" parameter there?

Comment: OK, I have it working now, but Im trying to clean the code up. It did redirect to the ABout page instead of the Index Action

Comment: We do Url.IsLocal for security reasons. Make sure you do this within all your controllers.

Comment: OK, Let me get it working and I will update the code above. I'll let you know if it breaks when I put in the Url.IsLocal, just need a few minutes

Comment: Well, since I am only passing it a string, how does it check that to see if it's local? 

When I add the IsLocal Stuff it breaks.

Comment: Make sure it is not null or empty:
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))

The first thing it does is check if the Url is fully qualified.

Comment: I just updated the code above I commented on the line that works and the line that doesn't . I would think that if the first line works the code block you gave me that checks local would work as well. Funny thing is the code block you gave me works when I take out the second check (&& Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))

Comment: Are you getting any errors or does Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) returns false?

Comment: No, Because it falls back to redirecting to the Index.

Comment: Must be returning false. Im confused because all it has to check is a string that equals "About" not sure how it could determine if that is local. Im lost there

Comment: Do not use "About" It must start with "/" or "~", so use "/About". This is how it works http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/600963a4df15#src/System.Web.WebPages/RequestExtensions.cs

Comment: OK Got it. Had to change the value of the Hidden Field to "/Home/About/"

Comment: I see, so if I did not have that check in place someone could redirect me to another site. And the reason it was working with just "About" but without the local check is because it was simply kicking it over to the ABout Action, but someone could easily just change that and have their way with it.

Comment: I'm updating the working code, I should be able to call this from any view now and for instance use a value of "/Products/List" or "/Accounts/Login" RIght?

Comment: I'm gonna add one more piece of code to the bottom and show you how I am using data from the database and showing English or spanish data without creating multiple views for each language.

Comment: Yes, that should work. If you need help with something else, I recommend creating a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture, string returnUrl)
    {
        // Validate input
        culture = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(culture);

        // Save culture in a cookie
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
        if (cookie != null)
            cookie.Value = culture;   // update cookie value
        else
        {

            cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
            cookie.Value = culture;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        }
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);


       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh man, I had something very similar to this earlier because I was loking how Accounts used returnUrl and checking for local...... Let me try

Comment: Also, in your view, add a hidden input called "returnUrl" with a value "/About".

Comment: Hey @NadeemAfana can u look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277959/i18n-with-renderaction ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using Nadeem's i18n solution in a project. The way you switch the culture in this project is through clicking on flags (anchor tags in image tags). I added a returnUrl and ended up with a redirect loop. To fix the redirect loop issue, I made a few changes to the code and ended up with this code:

File: BaseController.cs (added this method)

```
    public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture, string returnUrl)
    {
        // Validate input
        culture = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(culture);

        RouteData.Values["culture"] = culture;

        // Save culture in a cookie
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];

        if (cookie != null)
        {
            // update cookie value
            cookie.Value = culture;
        }
        else
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
            cookie.Value = culture;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        }

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

File: _layout.cshtml (flags for selecting culture):

```
            @{ var daDkUrl = Url.Action("setculture", "base", new { culture = "da-DK", returnUrl = Request.RawUrl }); }
            <a href="@daDkUrl">
                <img src="~/content/images/flag_da.gif" width="16" height="11" alt="Dansk" />
            </a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
            @{ var enUsUrl = Url.Action("setculture", "base", new { culture = "en-US", returnUrl = Request.RawUrl }); }
            <a href="@enUsUrl">
                <img src="~/content/images/flag_en.gif" width="16" height="11" alt="English" />
            </a>
```

Finally, ensure your controllers inherit from BaseController.cs.

```
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    //Code
}
```